# Example of a Chief series

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

Can you give an example of a non solvable group whose at least one Chief factor is a product of more than one simple group (i.e. it should not be a simple group).

Edit: Thanks @HallaSurvivor for suggestion. I am a Research scholar in mathematics. I have enough background in group theory.

The reason why I am asking this questions is that I have not study this concept of Chief series before. Almost all the example I have seen has the chief factors which are simple. But by definition it can be product of simple. So I just wanted to see such examples.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It's probably worth including a description of any ideas you might have, context for why you're asking this question, and any facts you know about Chief Series in the question. Currently this is a bit tricky to answer, because we don't know your background and motivation, and it's also liable to get closed because it looks "low effort". Adding some extra description will solve both problems ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct such examples using *wreath products*.

The smallest example is $G=A_5 \wr C_2$, the wreath product of the simple group $A_5$ with the cyclic group of order $2$.

It has a normal subgroup $N \cong A_5 \times A_5$, which is also a chief factor, and $|G/N| = 2$. If $g \in G \setminus N$, and we denote the two direct factors of $N$ by $N_1$ and $N_2$, then $g^{-1}N_1g = N_2$ and $g^{-1}N_2g = N_1$.

Comment: Thank you @Derek Holt.  Is {e} $\trianglelefteq $  $A_5 \times A_5$ $\trianglelefteq $ G a chief series of G?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Okay ,thank you!